# What is this error when I trying to change app icon in a flutter project

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-test

> C:\Users\Kumudu
>   Wijewardhana\AndroidStudioProjects\testing_app\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\app
>   icon.png: Resource and asset merger: ' ' is not a valid file-based
>   resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only
>   lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
>   > C:\Users\Kumudu Wijewardhana\AndroidStudioProjects\testing_app\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\app
>   >     icon.png: Error: ' ' is not a valid file-based resource name
>   >     character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z,
>   >     0-9, or underscore
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 0):

Check the name of icon.

The error is `File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore`

Lets change the name correct validate.

Comment: please give me an example .

Comment: Also I tried it but still happening the same thing.

Comment: remove all app icon file and try it one more time. Recommend to you try to use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons. Hope it helpful

Comment: I got it. The name should be ic_launcher.png

Comment: All the app icon name should be ic_launcher.png(This is worked for me!!)

Answer (score 0):

The error is talking about your app icon having a space(" ") in its name.
You should change your app icon name to `app_icon.png` instead of `app icon.png`.

Do not add space(" ") to the name of your resources.

Comment: it says:  app-icon.png: Error: '-' is not a valid file-based

Comment: Ohh sorry.
i meant underscore("_"), i updated my answer. `app_icon.png`